# How do I convert a large string to an integer in C#?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, integer

I am trying to convert a string which could be anywhere from 2 to 96 digits long and store it as an integer, but everything I've tried leads to OverflowException. Is there a certain way to convert a very large number?

My code converts a string input by the user into an array of the corresponding ASCII values of the each character in the input and then concatenates all the values of the array into a string, which I am then trying to convert into an integer.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger)

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netframework-4.8

BigInteger may be useful

Comment: using System.Numerics;

namespace BigNumTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myBigNumber = "123456789213646578912345678912345600";

            var myBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(myBigNumber);

            myBigInt = myBigInt + 99;

            Console.WriteLine(myBigInt);
        }
    }
}